# SQL Server : creating a trigger to only run when a specific table is being created

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If I know the specific table that's being created. Can I configure the trigger to execute only when a specific table is created?

```
 CREATE TRIGGER tr_trigger
 ON ALL SERVER
 FOR CREATE_TABLE
 AS
 ....
 GO
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible. Please refer to the following article on stackoverflow:

[SQL SERVER 2008 TRIGGER ON CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417871/sql-server-2008-trigger-on-create-table)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The link contains the information for the OP's scenario.

Comment: The 'TyT' answer provided at the link in this answer is spot on.  Its a link to a SOF article.  No reason to downvote this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for can be found in this article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.105).aspx

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR CREATE_TABLE  
AS 
   PRINT 'You are not allowed to create a table' 
   ROLLBACK
;
```

Comment: You didn't read my question...

Comment: I only want the trigger to execute on a specific table.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The link contains the information for the OP's scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers
  WHERE name = 'ddl_trig_database')
  DROP TRIGGER ddl_trig_database
  ON ALL SERVER;
  GO
  CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_database 
  ON ALL SERVER 
  FOR CREATE_DATABASE 
 AS 
   PRINT 'Database Created.'
   SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)         [1]','nvarchar(max)')
  GO
  DROP TRIGGER ddl_trig_database
 ON ALL SERVER;
  GO
```